# How can I make auto-complete work with ELPY in emacs?

Tags: autocomplete, elpy

I am trying to configure my emacs for python programming. Elpy auto-complete suggestion is not working at all in all instances. Any suggestions?

Here is my `elpy-config`...

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.31.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python 3.7.4 (/Users/mdmorshed/.pyenv/shims/python)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/Users/mdmorshed/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.7.4 (/Users/mdmorshed/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.15.1
 Rope.............: 0.14.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.4.4
 Yapf.............: 0.28.0
 Black............: 19.3b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/local/bin/flake8)

You have not activated a virtual env. While Elpy supports this, it is
often a good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use M-x
pyvenv-activate or M-x pyvenv-workon to activate a virtual env.

The directory ~/.local/bin/ is not in your PATH. As there is no active
virtualenv, installing Python packages locally will place executables
in that directory, so Emacs won't find them. If you are missing some
commands, do add this directory to your PATH -- and then do
`elpy-rpc-restart'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Elpy is suppose to provide auto-completion out-of-the-box. As your `elpy-config` seems fine, I would suggest reporting the issue in Elpy repository [here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues).